# Share sessions between laravel app and magento

Tags: laravel, session, magento, cookies, magento2

I have an application of laravel that is on main domain i want to share session with subdomain.com which is on magento ! there would be a button on main website on laravel dashboard to go to store of magento and when user lands on it session should be created automatically like single sign on, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is many approach for example in micro service architecture there is special engine (app) to manage authentication, but for now
To keep your sessions going across multiple domains, you need to use

`session_set_cookie_params()`. With that, you can specify your domain. For example...

```
session_set_cookie_params(10000, "/", ".main.com");
```

That will set the session timeout at 10,000 seconds for all documents under the site root, and for all subdomains of main.com.

You should call `session_set_cookie_params()` before you do `session_start()`.

Note: to achieve this functionality there is bunch of method but keep your own track and dive deep in all approach s